# How to set Browser Properties of Selenium Nodes?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I want to manipulate the browser properties of the Selenium Nodes. I use the [selenium/node-chrome](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-chrome/) docker image for nodes (but potentially I want to do this on Firefox nodes, too) inside Selenium Grid on an Kubernetes (Minikube) Cluster.

The properties I want to manipulate are

```
navigator.webdriver
screen.width
screen.height
navigator.deviceMemory
```

but I am searching a way that works for most browser properties, I may later find other properties I want to change. The browser properties do not have to change during a scan, and they do not need to be set inside my python code, it is all fine for me to change them in the nodes configuration, docker image or spoof them elsewhere.

I wrote a python script to read out the current values of those properties

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities=getattr(DesiredCapabilities, "CHROME")
)
print("navigator.webdriver: "+str(driver.execute_script("return navigator.webdriver")))
print("screen.width: "+str(driver.execute_script("return screen.width")))
print("screen.height: "+str(driver.execute_script("return screen.height")))
print("navigator.deviceMemory: "+str(driver.execute_script("return navigator.deviceMemory")))
driver.quit()
```

How can I change these properties?

EDIT: The K8s deployment of the node looks like this:

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: selenium-node-chrome
  labels:
    app: selenium-node-chrome
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: selenium-node-chrome
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: selenium-node-chrome
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: selenium-node-chrome
        image: selenium/node-chrome
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5555
        volumeMounts:
          - name: dshm
            mountPath: /dev/shm
          - name: config
            mountPath: /opt/selenium/config.json
            subPath: config.json
        env:
          - name: HUB_HOST
            value: "selenium-hub"
          - name: HUB_PORT
            value: "4444"
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "1000Mi"
            cpu: ".5"
      volumes:
      - name: dshm
        emptyDir:
          medium: Memory
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: selenium-node-chrome
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: selenium-node-chrome
data:
  config.json: |
    {
      "capabilities": [
        {
          "version": "81.0.4044.92",
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
          "applicationName": ""
        }
      ],
      "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
      "maxSession": 1,
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 5555,
      "register": true,
      "registerCycle": 5000,
      "nodePolling": 5000,
      "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
      "downPollingLimit": 2,
      "debug": false
    }
```

Comment: You mean that you want to change the values of the properties using python code?

Comment: It would be fine to change them in the Python file, but it is not have to be changed there, it is fine for me if it could be done within the K8s Deployment file or the nodes config file, too.

Comment: Then we need additional info too from your K8s config file.

Comment: I've added the configmap, but I'm not sure if it will be helpful...